# Sass specify parent

Tags: css, sass

I'm new to sass and looking for the syntax to specify a hierarchical relationship with code in the child class definition.

Currently I have:

```
.my-option
  color: #7E57EE
```

I'd like my sass to compile to the following CSS:

```
.my-option
  color: #7E57EE

.is-active .my-option
  background-color: #BADA55
```

I know two ways to accomplish this:

```
//More verbose than I'd like (and just plain css...)     
.my-option
  color: #7E57EE

.is-active .my-option
  background-color: #BADA55

//Too generic because...don't want the is-active definition to be cluttered
.my-option
  color: #7E57EE

.is-active
  .my-option
    background-color: #BADA55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`&`](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector) at the end of the contextual selector, which will put your child class there for you:

```
.my-option
  color: #7E57EE

  .is-active &
    background-color: #BADA55
```

Since you're writing Sass, be sure to indent the second rule so that the compiler will interpret it correctly.